# Using if-else and foor loop inside an always block

Tags: verilog

I want to use `if-else` and `for` loop inside an `always` block. I don't want those `if-else` to be executed again and again, so I don't want to connect always with either `posedge clk`or `negedge clk`.

I want them to be executed only once. I not only want to simulate but I want to synthesize on to Spartan Board aswell.

```
always @ (**what I should add here**)
    begin
    if(condition)

    else

    end
```

Comment: What circuit are you trying to describe?

Comment: Did you read any of the answers you got the last two times you asked this question?

Comment: What I was trying to ask in the previous 2 questions was infact general. I have already read the answers there. What simply I am asking is that I just want to use if-else statements. Without using always I am getting errors. That means these statements has to be inside always block. Right??. Now how should I execute always block exactly once. I have not got my answers in the previous questions which I asked.

Comment: I think you're not getting good answers because what you're trying to do doesn't really make sense in hardware. If you only want it to execute once, then **when** do you want it to execute? At power-on? After reset? After some event? You can use initial block for simulation, but that is not synthesizable. If you can answer *1) When do you want the block to execute?* and *2) What are you trying to do?* then maybe you can get some help. This question doesn't really make sense as-is.

Comment: Also to answer your question in the comment: Yes, if/else and other flow control statements must be inside an always block.

Comment: "I don't want those if-else to be executed again and again" - Why? If you can explain this it makes the question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Note that for loops are not synthesizable unless they are used to generate code.

Answer (score 3):

For simulations to execute some thing once you can use `initial` but this is not a synthesizable:

```
reg x;

initial begin
  if(condition) begin
    x = 1'b0 ;
  end
  else begin
    x = 1'b1 ;
  end
end
```

To answer the general question `always @(**what I should add here**)` Most modern verilog simulators will allow the use of `*` which will trigger the block (always begin to end) when any right hand side argument changes of any condition of selection logic.

```
always @* begin
  if(condition)
    x =  y ;
  else
    x = ~y ;
end
```

older simulators would require you to list the variables you needed to trigger on, in a list. `always @(condition, y)`

If there is only 1 variable being selected an assign on a wire type might be better, but this can not be limited to being 'executed once', but would be a suitable choice from your question. Not sure about suitability for FPGA's though

```
wire [3:0] x ; //4 bit wire
//(condition) ? value if true : value if false ;
assign x = (condition) ? 4'b1010 : 4'b0100 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module oneShot(in, out, enable, reset);
    input in;
    input enable;
    input reset;
    output reg out;

    reg once_only;
    always @ (posedge enable) begin
          if (reset) begin
                once_only <= 0;
          end              
          else if (once_only == 0) begin
                out <= calc_out; // or whatever processing you want
                once_only <= 1;
          end
    end

    always @(*) begin
          // calculate ouput here always
          calc_out = 1 +  7 +100+ in;
    end
endmodule
```

You can't have those if statements calculate only once. It's hardware, it'll always calculate. But you can hold the output steady after it's been calculated once. You are still trying to write a software function and put it in to hardware rather than describe hardware which will solve your problem. I can't see that you'll get a decent design this way. Sure you'll be able to make some small pieces and synthesise them (eventually), but a full design??